# How does node/nest.js send the access token passed from the front end to ourself Oauth2 authentication server and verify it

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Tku.png)

this is error
How does node/nest.js send the access token passed from the front end to ourself Oauth2 authentication server and verify it

Answer (score 0):

Resource server access OAuth2 authentication server